# HTML email form PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have a HTML form that works with PHP code, and i get the emails sent to me, however, i can get an email if there is no subject, no email and no message. Maybe some one know how to fix that? Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'benasleng@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to benasleng@gmail.com');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
<?php
function IsInjected($str)
{
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
           '(\r+)',
           '(\t+)',
           '(%0A+)',
           '(%0D+)',
           '(%08+)',
           '(%09+)'
           );

    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";

    if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
}

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you asking how _not_ to send e-mails if subject / email / message are empty? Should be a simple set of `if` conditions. What are you stuck with?

Comment: Don't just run `mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers)` check first. Also `isinjected` is not used until after the email has sent, might want to fix that. Also not clear why certain whitespaces make an email "injected"..

Comment: Also, please use [header](http://php.net/header) redirects rather than that rather nasty JS hack.

Comment: This php code is not mine, I just got it from some tutorial i've read. I don't know anything about php...

Comment: Okay. Time to stop reading the tutorial and find a better one.

Comment: But why is this a bad code shown in that tutorial?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

before calling mail() function,  you should check if fields are compiled .

This is just a draft example because i suggest you to use more complex checks than just empty() function, expecially on $field_email, for example:

```
if (empty($field_name) || !filter_var($field_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) || empty($field_message)) {
  ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('All fields must be correctly compiled');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php

} else {


$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to benasleng@gmail.com');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding headers and using the mail() function:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Mail <mail@mail.someadress.com>';

mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
```